# Prepare date data for dumbbell plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalt

I have a dataset that presents a few challenges for transformation in preparation for creating a dumbbell plot:

1. Single Date Groups: Some groups have only one date. In these cases, the start and end dates are the same, and `h_sequ` is `1`.
2. Two Date Groups: Other groups have a clear start and end date, signified by `h_sequ` values of `1` and `2`. An example of this is group 12.
3. Three Date Groups: There are also groups with three dates, where `h_sequ` takes values 1, 2, and 3, such as group 33.
4. And also in group 33 there is a unique case where `h_sequ` has values of `1, 1, 2, 3`.

```
 group h_sequ date      
   <int>  <int> <date>    
 1     1      1 2012-03-27
 2     1      1 2012-03-27
 3    10      1 2016-10-25
 4    10      1 2016-10-25
 5    12      1 2021-06-25
 6    12      2 2022-05-18
 7    31      1 2019-11-28
 8    31      1 2019-11-28
 9    31      2 2021-03-24
10    33      1 2013-09-03
11    33      1 2013-09-03
12    33      2 2019-01-04
13    33      3 2020-07-28
14    35      1 2015-10-21
15    35      2 2017-06-28

data <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 35L, 35L), h_sequ = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), date = structure(c(15426, 
15426, 17099, 17099, 18803, 19130, 18228, 18228, 18710, 15951, 
15951, 17900, 18471, 16729, 17345), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

The main question is how to implement the logic for the date column to accommodate these scenarios in a combined dumbbell plot. So far, I have used summarization to get the minimum and maximum dates for each group, but I need to integrate this approach with the specific structure of my data, taking into account the varying number of dates per group.

So far I have this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  summarise(start_date = min(date), end_date = max(date), .by = group) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = start_date, xend = end_date, y = group)) +
  geom_dumbbell(color = "red3", size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: A bit irrelevant but please change group to factor. What do you expect to plot for group 10 and 1, I don't see the issue with min/max approach.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with the current approach? Looks like it works just fine. But I'm also only familiar with dumbbells with 1 beginning and 1 end point (which is what `geom_dumbbell` seems to expect). How is your data or plotting goal different from what you're getting for, say, group 33 with it's odd 1,1,2,3 structure? Do you want 5 dumbbells plotted for group 33, corresponding to each non-equal pair of `h_sequ` values? Or are you hoping for dumbbells with more than 2 points? Or something else?

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you for your reply. For group33: Do 2 things on 2013-09-03, Next thing on 2019-01-04 and last thing on 2020-07-28. Thing could be everything, for example a surgery. [Here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/06/make-multi-point-dumbbell-plots-in-ggplot2/) it is shown how to make a "multipoint" dumbbell plot. I expect 3 points in the "dumbbell" of group 33.

Comment: @zx8754. I wish to solve the starting point with one date for two events. So both are lying on each other. I could subtract some days to show them both or I could do jittering... the second thing is. I would expect a third point in the group 33. And finally thank you for factor. This is correct.

Comment: Here is the way how to format for dumbbell plot https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.r-bloggers.com/2021/08/ggalt-make-a-dumbbell-plot-to-visualize-change-in-ggplot2/amp/

Comment: @Umar Thank you very much. But believe me, I think I have reviewed most pages discussing dumbbell plots (including your suggestion).

Comment: @TarJae what's wrong with geom_point plus geom_linerange? You could dodge the points that occur on the same day if you wanted.

Comment: Ok. I'm slowly realizing that focusing solely on the dumbbell plot has blinded me to the simpler approaches!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably manually dodge the co-occurring points, and join the points with `geom_path`. This allows a complete display of all your data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  mutate(group = factor(group)) %>%
  mutate(dodge = (row_number() - median(row_number()))/n()/3.2, 
                  .by = c(group, date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, group)) +
  geom_path(linewidth = 3, color = "gray") +
  geom_point(aes(y = as.numeric(group) + dodge, fill = factor(h_sequ)), 
             shape = 21, size = 5) +
  scale_fill_manual("h_sequ", values = c("orange", "deepskyblue4", "red4")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Much nicer dodging adjustment than mine (and nicer colors too :)

Comment: @Allan Cameron. thank you. I was nearly there; the dodging is perfect. I attempted jittering and was looking for a way to assign a different color to the dodged points. Is there an easy way to color the dodged points with a different color?

Comment: @TarJae, sure, `color = dodge != 0` inside `aes()` to distinguish between dodged/non-dodged points. Or if that's not what you mean you could add another column to the data however you like.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest building your own dumbbells using `geom_segment` and `geom_point`:

```
ends = data |> summarise(start_date = min(date), end_date = max(date), .by = group)
data = data |> mutate(nudge = (row_number() - 1) / 2, .by = c(group, h_sequ))

ggplot(ends, aes(y = group)) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = start_date, xend = end_date, y = group, yend = group),
    color = "red3", linewidth = 3
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = data,
    aes(x = date, y = group + nudge, fill = factor(h_sequ)), 
    color = "gray20",
    shape = 21,
    alpha = 0.9,
    size = 4
  )
```

[image]